# Which conditions should I set in InfoPath rules to swap a view when an item is opened?

Tags: list, infopath, list-view

I have four views. On the first view I've set field to be mandatory and then a Form Load rule saying that if that field is not blank to swap the view which works great. Then when I go into edit the item in the list I want it to switch to the third view with a new rule again saying if a field in the view is not blank to switch view, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it the same filed you put First form load rule on !

Comment: Do you mean is it the same form? If so then yes.  Both rules are on Form Load. I thought maybe setting up a View and rules on the list itself might work?

Comment: no, I meant that you put a form load  rule that is working fine, but the your second rule is not working !   On which field did you put the form rule, is it the same field that first  rule running on !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that we can add different rules for different views. But as a workaround,

1. Create one field in list says "NextView" &  set the default value as "Main".
2. On submitting every view, set "NextView" value to name of next view after current view. (For example, while submitting your main view, set "NextView" field value to the view you want to switch at next form load) do this for all view submit operation.
3. Now on form load, write 4 conditions & within conditions, check  if your "NextView" field value is equals to xyz then **switch the view** to xyz.

So, Whenever you open your form, it checks the NextView condition and switch to specific view.

Hope this help.